# How to share file in android

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I'm created an app that will send a file using action send, after an hour my code doesn't work.

when it open the other app i get an error "Transferring such content type not supported" for shareIt and for bluetooth file iamafile was not sent to ... here's my code, i tried a lot of code but doesn't work. pls help

```
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/QuizApp/MyAnswer/"+sharedPreferenceUsername +"/"+ editTitle);
                        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(root);


                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                        intent.setType("*/*");
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

                        startActivity(intent);
```

by the way editTitle is a File.

Answer (score 8):

**Share Any File as below ( Kotlin ) :**
first create a folder named *`xml`* in the *`res`* folder and create a new XML Resource File named *`provider_paths.xml`* and put the below code inside it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="."/>

    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="."/>
</paths>
```

now go to the *`manifests`* folder and open the *`AndroidManifest.xml`* and then put the below code inside the `<application>` tag :

```
<provider
android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
android:exported="false"
android:grantUriPermissions="true">
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" /> // provider_paths.xml file path in this example
</provider>
```

now you put the below code in the `setOnLongClickListener` :

```
try {
    val file = File("pathOfFile")
    if(file.exists()) {
        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        intent.setType("*/*")
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent)
    }
} catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    toast("Error")
}
```

I hope this be useful

Answer (score 0):

I've got this working for multiple video files. You could change some lines in order to be complient to your needs.

Sorry, it's written in kotlin, but I think it's understandable enough.

```
val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE)
        val files = ArrayList<Uri>()
        files.add(<first file URI>)
    ...
        files.add(<n th file URI>)
        //here set the type wanted. I think that */* is a bad idea because the app could catch it even if the type is not good
        sharingIntent.type = "video/*"
        sharingIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files)
        sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        context.startActivity(sharingIntent)
```

Comment: thanks man. its strange its worked again even if i didnt change something